# LightSwitch and IIS 7 Windows Authentication

Tags: iis-7, visual-studio-lightswitch

I ask this under the pretense of LightSwitch as that is what I am trying to deploy even though I have a sneaky suspicion that it has nothing to do with it.

If I have Authentication Enabled in any form on any App Type for LS I get the

> "Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

I have the LS Pre-reqs installed on a clean ms08 Server.  I used Web Platform to install almost everything.  I have installed Fiddler2 and I am guessing I am not using it right as all it says is that `GET /EpistemeAdmin/Web/Microsoft-LightSwitch-Security-ServerGenerated-Implementation-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/GetAuthenticationInfo HTTP/1.1`

Is moved, renamed, or in-accessible.

I deployed the site through Web Deploy and it has it's own App Pool.  Only Windows Authentication is enabled.

I understand this seems more like an IIS issue so maybe this should go to ServerFault but I thought I'd try LightSwitch angle first in case others had encountered the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue on Windows 2012.
Had to enable http activation under WCF under the .NET 4.5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on another thread --> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/a2650616-1b68-4ae9-9ffd-f4f2a1211254

I simply repaired the .NET 4 Client (*on the IIS Server*), restarted and **BAM**!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody having the same problem:

The first line in my web.config was

```
<add key="UserCodeAssemblies" value="Application.Common.dll;Application.Server.dll;Application.ServerGenerated.dll"/>
```

after switching to:

```
  <add key="UserCodeAssemblies" value="Application.Common.dll;Application.Server.dll;"/>
```

the problem went away.

Way to debug this:

publish your lightswitch to a folder. Unzip and open the web site using visual studio.File->open->website